# Geometry Nodes. How do I shift a plain's vertex position based on whether or not a selected object hits it/ lands on it?

Tags: node-editor, geometry, geometry-nodes

I've made this simple plain, and used it's noise attribute to guide positions of instances,
Wherever the ground is lower than a certain z,

1. The grass is thicker
2. There are pebbles
   Node Trees Below
   [image]

[image]

Is there a way I can tell this ground plain to bend (move points -z), 12 frames after an object (a mesh, a ball, a cube) lands on the ground (via external/geometry nodes animation)??

I want do it in a way that the bending caused by external objects is added to the current noise pattern. The pebbles in the further node tree would then appear and over up the object that had fallen.

Basically a ground that eats up objects that land on it (except the pebbles and grass that are already on the plain)

Comment: And how do the pebbles land on the ground? Is there an existing animation? ...it looks more like physics to me.

Comment: @quellenform I will add that animation, thought I could do it after I set up the nodes for ground. Basic drop animation from viewport or geometry nodes I'm thinking

Comment: @quellenform BTW, the pebbles you see stay on the ground, they don't land. But I wanna make some other object (mesh) land on the ground and that should affect the displacement of z in ground plane, and in turn it would tell my current pebbles where to appear

Comment: Correction: A ground that eats up selected objects that land on it, but it doesn't eat the pebbles or the grass.

Comment: Solved. Used Raycasting on realised instances.

Comment: Would you be so kind and write a short answer and mark it as "Accepted Answer"? That would reduce the number of "unsolved" questions here a bit and help others to find the right answer more easily. Thank you!